# Ffind ALL images in a Word file

Tags: vba, image, ms-word

I want to find ALL references to pictures in a Word file (it is a .doc file but I can save it in .docx or whatever; I'm using Office 2016 on Windows 10) and write them to file (for further processing like copying them into a separate folder).
I looked at some other questions but didn't find the answer.

My code below will save the names of most pictures in my file but only if
`.Type = msoLinkedPicture`    or     `.Type = wdInlineShapeLinkedPicture`

```
Sub GetPictureNames()
    Dim FileOut As String
    FileOut = "c:\Temp\Images\Pictures.txt"
    Open FileOut For Output As #1

    Dim numOne As Integer, numTwo As Integer, numThree As Integer, numFour As Integer, numFive As Integer, numSix As Integer
    numOne = 0: numTwo = 0: numThree = 0: numFour = 0: numFive = 0: numSix = 0
   
    Dim strShapeRange As String
    Dim strInlineShapes As String
   
    With ActiveDocument.Range
      For Each Shp In .ShapeRange
        With Shp
            If (.Type = msoLinkedPicture) Then
                numOne = numOne + 1
                Print #1, .LinkFormat.SourceFullName
            ElseIf (.Type = msoPicture) Then
                numTwo = numTwo + 1
            Else
                numThree = numThree + 1
            End If
        End With
      Next Shp
      
      For Each iShp In .InlineShapes
        With iShp
            If (.Type = wdInlineShapeLinkedPicture) Then
                numFour = numFour + 1
                Print #1, .LinkFormat.SourceFullName
            ElseIf (.Type = wdInlinePicture) Then
                numFive = numFive + 1
            Else
                numSix = numSix + 1
            End If
        End With
      next iShp
  end with

   strShapeRange = "msoLinkedPicture: " & numOne & vbCr & "msoPicture: " & numTwo & vbCr & "else_ShapeRange: " & numThree & vbCr
   strInlineShapes = vbCr & "wdInlineShapeLinkedPicture: " & numFour & vbCr & "wdInlinePicture: " & numFive & vbCr & "else_InlineShapes: " & numSix
   MsgBox strShapeRange & strInlineShapes
   
   Close #1
End Sub
```

How can I access all other pictures (.type = MsoPicture or .type = wdInlinePicture  or  whatever) to be able to save them or to get access to their origin?

Comment: Word *cannot* tell you the source of a picture unless it has the 'linked' attribute.

Comment: @macropod I suspected that. But how can I retrieve those pictures that are not linked

Comment: Retrieve them how? They're already in the document.

Comment: I want to get them out

Comment: See: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f2920489-1605-4eab-8781-c6cdc140426c/how-to-save-word-document-pictures-to-a-folder